# Which parameter should be first `old` or `new`?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I've created function `replaceElement`. I'm not sure if `old` parameter should be first or second. What is common way for parameter order in this case?

```
void replaceElement(Element *old, Element *n);
```

or

```
void replaceElement(Element *n, Element *old);
```

Comment: i think its simple as you would say it. "replace the old flowers with new ones." sounds right to me.

Comment: What is wrong with providing a copy/move constructor, assignment operator or even custom function in the ELement class/struct itself? Then you can write `n = old` or `n.replaceby(old)` or even `Element new{old}`; All these language constructs are there for a reason, this is not something that should go in a nonmember funtion (unless it's an assignment operator).

Comment: May be better: "current" and "new"? Order "current" is first is better (coming from standard c-library paradigm "destination argument first")

Comment: Shouldn't one or both of those be `const`? And unless you're replacing pointers with other pointers, shouldn't they be references?

Comment: @Potatoswatter Why reference? This class should be able to cast no `const` functions to elements and replace function is used in case of event from outside of class that replace certain element with another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would choose `void replaceElement(Element *old, Element *n);`

It sounds better for me, and also you might want to make a default parameter later. And the default in your case will be `new`.

Also that's how `std::replace` is formed:

```
template< class ForwardIterator, class T >
void replace( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
              const T& old_value, const T& new_value );
```

Comment: +1 & accept because of providing the example

Answer (score 1):

In c++ it's usually first destination then source
so i had say destination = old and source = new

Answer (score 1):

First old, then new. You name the function `replaceElement`. So you read:

```
void replaceElement(Element* old, Element* n);
```

as:

> replace element `old` with `n`